# AWS EC2: Add a tag when launching an instance using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

If you want to add a tag to an instance when launching, you have to perform two steps:

1. Launch an instance (`run-instances`)
2. Add a tag to the newly created instance (`create-tags`)

Is there a way to add a tag (or set a name) when launching an instance using a single CLI command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This request had been pending for a long time and AWS finally supported this in `March 2017`.

See: [Amazon EC2 and Amazon EBS add support for tagging resources upon creation and additional resource-level permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/amazon-ec2-and-amazon-ebs-add-support-for-tagging-resources-upon-creation-and-additonal-resource-level-permissions)

---

Make sure your AWS CLI version is at least **1.11.106**

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.109 Python/2.6.9 Linux/4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.5.72
```

---

CLI to tag the instance when launching:

> The following example applies a tag with a key of `webserver` and
>   value of `production` to the instance.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro 
    --key-name MyKeyPair --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e
    --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]'
```

---

CLI to tag the instance and the volume:

> The command also applies a tag with a key of `cost-center` and a value
>   of `cc123` to any EBS volume that's created (in this case, the root
>   volume).

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro 
    --key-name MyKeyPair --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e
    --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}]'
```